# Show that $4 + \sqrt{10}$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}\bigl [\sqrt{10}\bigr]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm currently working through some extra problems while studying for an algebra exam. Right now, I am having trouble showing that $4+\sqrt{10}$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$. I've been trying to find elements $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ such that $ab \in (4 + \sqrt{10})$ but neither $a$ nor $b$ are in the ideal. This method worked well for showing that 2 and 3 are not prime in this ring, but I'm not having much success for this example. I know that I could also show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}] / (4 + \sqrt{10})$ is not an integral domain, but I don't think that simplifies anything. Is there another approach that I'm missing?

Comment: The norm of a prime element must be the power of a prime number, while $N(4+\sqrt{10})=6$ is not.

Comment: @Crostul $N(4+\sqrt{10})=6$.

Comment: How about using variabels like $ (a + b \sqrt 10 )(C + d \sqrt 10) = 4 + \sqrt 10 $ ?

Comment: @mick I should mention that I've already shown that $4 + \sqrt{10}$ is irreducible, so one of those factors would be a unit meaning that the other produces the same ideal as $4 + \sqrt{10}$. I'd need to look for a product that gives me a multiple of $4 + \sqrt{10}$ - which was giving me too many variables to work with!

Comment: Why must the norm of a prime be a prime power ? Assume it is 6 and 2,3 do not occur as norms ??

Comment: Actually it is easy to find out what $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}] / (4 + \sqrt{10})$ is. Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319287/prime-ideal-in-mathbb-z-sqrt10?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned $2$ and $3$ just after saying you needed $a$, $b$ with $a\notin I$, $b\notin I$ and $ab\in I$.

Comment: That I did. Now it makes sense why these numbers all belonged to the same problem.... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I like your second approach (showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}] / (4 + \sqrt{10})$ is not a domain), since it also tells you something about the factorization of the ideal $(4 + \sqrt{10})$.  By the Third Isomorphism Theorem and the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]}{(4 + \sqrt{10})} &\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 -10)}{(4 + x, x^2 - 10)/(x^2 - 10)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x + 4, x^2 - 10)}\\
&\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[-4]}{((-4)^2 - 10)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(6)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2)} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(3)} \, .
\end{align*}
Since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is not a domain, then $(4 + \sqrt{10})$ is not prime.  In fact, one can show that
$$
(4 + \sqrt{10}) = (2, 4 + \sqrt{10})(3, 4 + \sqrt{10}) \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+\sqrt{10})(2+\sqrt{10})\in (4+\sqrt{10})$$